# android shared userid for sharing specific shared preference value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a suite of 5 apps. Planning to use sharedUserId to share credentials across each app to implement single sign on(not correct approach). Credentials will be stored in a preference and each application has to check for the specific preference. if it is available, then loginAcitvity will be bypassed with the credentials. As per sharedUserId example, the preference is attached to  one application's context. How to have a common preference for all apps? As there could be a scenario that few apps might not be installed.

I'm not going with Accounts because it might quite sometime to implement for all the apps.

Comment: give  different name  of shared preference for two app

Comment: Already both the apps uses default shared preferences and they use some preferences with same key as well. It would be difficult to change the preferences in both the apps. So any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize you SharedPrefs like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("any_name",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

So it will be accesible from all apps.

Comment: I read that the preferences will be shared with other applications if MODE_WORLD_READABLE is used. I do not want to do that as i'm planning to share credentials. I'm not sure whether i have stated my question clearly. Sorry for that. I have edited the question. Can you check again?